# Why won't images load on mobile version of a website using html and css?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, jpeg

The images on my pen http://codepen.io/niffyy/pen/GNzpNW?editors=1100 wont load on a mobile screen.

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="container" id="third">
       <p class="para2"> Portfolio </p>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <div><a href='http://codepen.io/niffyy/full/VPZLpj/' class="thumbnail"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/YiCHp7M.jpg" alt="screenshot"></a><h5>Simple Nelson Mandela Tribute Page</h5> 
      </div>

       <div><a href='#' class="thumbnail"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mMJs4kq.png" alt="screenshot3"></a><h5> Coming soon!</h5>
</div> 

   </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
        <div><a href='http://codepen.io/niffyy/full/GNzpNW/' class="thumbnail"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/z5PtrqQ.jpg" alt="screenshot1"></a><h5> Portfolio Page</h5>
  </div> 

      <div><a href='#' class="thumbnail"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mMJs4kq.png" alt="screenshot2"></a><h5> Coming soon!</h5>
</div>



   </div>
   </div>
   </div>



 <div class="col-xs-6"> <img class="img-responsive" id="me" alt="a picture of me" src="http://i.imgur.com/EWx1Z9x.jpg">
      </div>
```

<--THE CSS-->

```
#me{
    width:100%; 
    height: auto;

  margin-top:45px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width:5px;
  border-radius:20px;
  border-color:#FF33CC;
}
```

I tried changing the format from png to jpeg and also resizing the image before uploading it but it still does not work This also goes for the thumbnails on the website and I am unsure why. I checked the code for mistakes but haven't seen where I am going wrong. It shows fine on desk top.

Comment: It has been loaded perfectly on mobile !

Comment: The imgur links are returning with 403 Forbidden errors for me. If I navigate directly to them and refresh, they load, but the hotlinking is broken on them right now. No clue why.

Comment: can I ask which mobile you are using? It does not load on my iphone 5 or when I test it on cross browser testing

Comment: Can you prune the example down to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem? As is it now, the first thing people see in the codepen is a perfectly loading background graphic, and the question obviously is not about that.

Comment: @MrLister The code snippet above is the code that I am running for only the images on the site. if you scroll past the home page you will see the unloaded images. I included the link to the pen incase people wanted to have a look at the full code.

Comment: @MrLister The example contains only the problem code

Answer (score 0):

I was using imgur.com to host my images then hot linking to my page. This is not in their terms of use which is why the images were not loading on my page. In future if anyone has the same issue as me, check that hotlinking is allowed for the image you are trying to use for your page. I switched hosting site to another and now my images work fine.

From the Imgur terms of use:

> 'We allow hotlinking on forums, but hotlinked images cannot be used as
>   content for a website, including blog posts, avatars, site elements,
>   and advertising. You can read our terms of service for more info